# Masturbation In Ramadan

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, masturbation

I wanted to ask that”I during fasting just moved my dick up and down 2 times without intention of masturbating.it stood up I felt uncomfortable and had urine after having it 1-2 drops came out of my dick. So if my fast still going or is broken”

Answer (score -1):

IF you did not intend on masterbating, then it's fine.
If you almost ejaculated after moving your hands up and down twice on your 'Dick', I suggest you have other things to worry about rather than if you broke your fast or not.